# Flutter IFrameElement does not change source

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have created the following stateless widget to display some web contents in my Flutter WPA.
Its parent is state-full and rebuilds this widget when the `_frameUrl` is changed.
But this happens only the first time. After that when the parent changes `_frameUrl` I can see in the logs that the widget is getting rebuilt and has got the new URL, but it still reloads with the old URL given the first time.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:universal_ui/universal_ui.dart';

class HtmlFrame extends StatelessWidget {
  var _iframeElement;
  final String _frameUrl;

  HtmlFrame(this._frameUrl);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Frame build: $_frameUrl");

    _iframeElement = IFrameElement();
    _iframeElement.height = '500';
    _iframeElement.width = '500';
    _iframeElement.src = _frameUrl;
    _iframeElement.style.border = 'none';
    _iframeElement.allowFullscreen = true;

    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'iframeElement',
      (int viewId) => (_iframeElement as IFrameElement),
    );

    return HtmlElementView(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      viewType: 'iframeElement',
    );
  }
}
```

Here what the log looks like:

```
### First URL: https://www.google.com

Frame build: http://www.google.com
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

### After giving it the second URL: https://www.bing.com

Frame build: https://www.bing.com/
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

I used google and bing for the above log samples to show how it again tries to load the first URL, for the sameorigin error logs the URL it tried. In my app there is not such problem and the URLs belong to a allowed website.

Answer (score 9):

Just have to give dynamic name while register you src url to ui. So best method and easy one is just pass url as register name ..In your code.

```
ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
  _frameUrl,
  (int viewId) => (_iframeElement as IFrameElement),
);

return HtmlElementView(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  viewType: _frameUrl,
);
```

That's it.

Comment: Hi I would like to try your code, but there is an error, can you tell me what is ```_iframeElement``` in your code ?

Comment: It works, but why exactly?